# Constant updating of a form in vb

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to constantly update a form? I have a game with 3 difficulties and you need a high score of atleast 5 to unlock the next difficulty, it works but for the difficulties to unlock you need to relaunch the application. Or i am guessing use a button to update the difficulties, This is the code i have on form load.

```
    EHighScore = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("EasyHighScore.txt")
    MHighScore = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("MediumHighScore.txt")
    HHighScore = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("HardHighScore.txt")


    If EHighScore < 5 Then
        MediumDifficulty.Enabled = False
        MediumDifficulty.BackColor = Color.Gray
    Else
        MediumDifficulty.Enabled = True
        MediumDifficulty.BackColor = Color.Black

    End If

    If MHighScore < 5 Then
        HardDifficulty.Enabled = False
        HardDifficulty.BackColor = Color.Gray
    Else
        HardDifficulty.Enabled = True
        HardDifficulty.BackColor = Color.Black
    End If
```

How would i make this run when the form opens when i close the end screen that displays the score the user got (plus highscore if they did beat the high score) I have tried to do MainMenu.Close() when opening the game but the same result happens as MainMenu.Hide()

Comment: It looks like `EHighScore` is a `String` holding the contents of a file. How can you compare a string to a number? If EHighScore < 5 Then

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: I declared EHighScore and the rest as global integer so i could transfer the variable and content it holds through forms

Comment: If it is declared as an Integer how do expect it will hold the contents of a text file?

Comment: It works fine though? I believe it only works because the only thing thats in the text file is the high score number, but if there was text then yeah it wouldn't work

Comment: That is a dangerous way to program. Turn on Option Strict of put it at the top of every code file.

Comment: For something like this, rather than running a timer or polling, I'd suggest that you should be managing your events and data binding so that part of the score update process is that it also checks for clearing a threshold and updates the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and manipulate the variables & **use a timer** tool to update changes of a form in real-time (set the interval to 1000ms).

For example, consider the following code:

Declaration:

```
Dim difficult As Boolean
```

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    difficult = True
End If
```

And the timer:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(...) Handles Timer1.Tick
    if difficult = True Then
        ' ...
    End If
End Sub
```

It will become easier for you to handle real-time things.

> Caution: Don't use this trick which requires a network. Otherwise, it'll make your program unresponsive.

Comment: So basically I can use timer tick and just put any code in it that i want to keep running?

Comment: Obviously, then your code will be kept updated every single second. That's what I do basically to handle application code for live changes (but not for networking).

Comment: I put the code in the original post into a timer.tick but it still isn't updating, i am having to use a button atm to click to then update the form

Comment: Make sure you've started the Timer from properties.

Comment: Thanks so much, got it working!!, quite new to visual studio/basic so sorry if i sound so dumb hahaa